# doctrine 2, one-to-one association, updates primary key in one entity when adding/deleting related entity

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have 2 entities
User and Address

User is mapped One to One (Unidirectional) to Address,
both have id/user_id field (primary) which is used for join
with cascade=persist and orphanRemoval=true

when I do
        $user = $em->find('\Classes\User',1);
        $user->removeAddress();
        $em->flush();

it deletes the address part from database which is expected,
**but why does it update id value to null in User object** ?

```
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class User
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue */
    private $id;
    /** @Column(length=100) */
    public $name;

    /** @OneToOne(targetEntity="Address", orphanRemoval=true) 
     * @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     */
    public $address;

    public function removeAddress()
    {
        unset($this->address);
    }
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Address
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") */
    public $user_id;

    /** @Column(length=100) */
    public $street_name;

    public function __construct($id, $name) {
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you add full code of relevant relations/associations.

Comment: What would you expect to happen precisely? If the address record is removed, it can no longer be referred to by the User table

Comment: yes that is right, but it is updating the id in User object to null which is also the primary key for User object, which needs to stay